# How can I declare a hash function for use in an unordered_set within a namespace?

Tags: c++, hash

I've successfully created a hash function (and `==` override) for a custom class so I can use it in an `unordered_set`. However, ideally I'd like to define the template specialization for my class near the class that it's to be used for. This can be done by the following, which works fine:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { _id = _nextId++; }
    const int id() const { return _id; }
private:
    int _id;
    static int _nextId;
};

int MyClass::_nextId = 0;

template<>
struct std::hash<MyClass> {
    std::size_t operator()(const MyClass& k) const {
        return k.id();
    }
};
```

However, `MyClass` is declared in a custom namespace. I thought that using the global scope resolution operator `::`, but that doesn't work:

```
namespace mine {
    // ...

    template<>
    struct ::std::hash<MyClass> {
        // ...
    };
}
```

So, it seems like I want to have something within the enclosing braces of a namespace declare something to be in another namespace. Writing that last sentence makes me realize that this is probably not possible, but the idea of having the hash function near the class it's hashing seems like a good idea.

Is this possible? What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've discovered, if you want to add a specialization for `std::hash` that must be done within the `std` namespace. If this is undesirable, another option is to keep the hash functor within your namespace and pass it as a template argument to [`unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)

```
namespace mine {

class MyClass { ... };

struct MyClass_hash {
  std::size_t operator()(const MyClass& k) const {
    return k.id();
  }
};

}

std::unordered_set<mine::MyClass, mine::MyClass_hash> my_set;
```

You can also create a `typedef` for the `unordered_set` to save yourself some typing.

Comment: +1 That's the preferred solution. You can also, later on, define a specialization of `std::hash` as `struct hash<MyClass> : MyClass_hash { };` in the std-namespace. Another option is to have a very simple specialization of `std::hash` that simply calls a "hash" member function in MyClass or a free-function that takes a MyClass object. The point is, you can keep all the hashing code close to the MyClass definition by making the `std::hash` into a very thin wrapper (and comment on the actual hash function or class to say that it's thinly wrapped in a specialization of `std::hash`).

Answer (score 1):

You can specialise `std::hash` for your type enclosing this in a standard namespace:

```
namespace std {
    template <>
    struct hash<mine::MyClass> {
    std::size_t operator()( const mine::MyClass& k) const {
        return k.id();
    }
}
```

This is the way to specialize std::hash. Alternatively you can create a custom functor and pass it to hash table. You can then do anything as your hash, e.g:

```
namespace mine {

class MyClass { ... };

    template<typename T>
    struct Hash : public std::unary_function<T, uint16_t> {
        uint16_t operator()(T const&) const;
    };

typedef boost::unordered_multimap< MyClass, value, Hash<MyClass> > HashMMap;

}
```

Comment: I would ideally like to have the code for the hash function physically near the code for the class itself. I suppose I could have all my class member definitions in global scope and specify the namespace for every one, but I would like to simply put them into a namespace block. This would require closing the block and opening another, possibly moving the definition of the hash function away from the class member definitions.

Comment: you can paste this into your MyClass.h