# c++11 unordered_set with hash function syntax error

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, unordered-set

I've this code:

```
#include<unordered_set>
using namespace std;
struct E{
    size_t distance;
    bool operator>(const E& e)const{
        return distance > e.distance;
    }
    bool operator<(const E& e)const{
        return distance < e.distance;
    }
};
int main(){
    unordered_set<E> s;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with g++ 7.3 it gives a lot of errors:

```
g++ m.cpp -std=c++11
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                from /usr/include/c++/7/unordered_set:47,
                from m.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<E, std::hash<E> >’:
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits:143:12:   required from ‘struct std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<E> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<E, std::hash<E> > >’
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits:154:31:   required from ‘struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<E> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<E, std::hash<E> > > >’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unordered_set.h:98:63:   required from ‘class std::unordered_set<E>’
m.cpp:13:22:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:87:34: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<E>) (const E&)’
noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/move.h:54:0,
                from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                from /usr/include/c++/7/utility:70,
                from /usr/include/c++/7/unordered_set:38,
                from m.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<E> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<E, std::hash<E> > > >’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unordered_set.h:98:63:   required from ‘class std::unordered_set<E>’
m.cpp:13:22:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits:154:31: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<E> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<E, std::hash<E> > >’
    : public __bool_constant<!bool(_Pp::value)>
```

Where did I get wrong, how to fix it?

Comment: You did not provide the logic how to hash your `E` struct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I declare a hash function for use in an unordered\_set within a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796594/how-can-i-declare-a-hash-function-for-use-in-an-unordered-set-within-a-namespace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unordered_set` does not require `operator<` and `operator>` for your type `E`, which you have provided. It does require a hash function or function-like object (or defaults to  `std::hash<E>`) which you have not provided, as well as `operator==`, which you have also not provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot provide `std::hash<E>` you can switch to a `std::map` which will be slower though.